# How to use a number in a list as a bench mark for comparison

Tags: python, integer

I have written some code but would like to make it more simple.

How can I extract the desired integer from my list without all the extra lines of code which turn it into an integer so I can use it in my if statement?

```
def nextRound(k,scores):
    count = 0
    integers = scores[k-1:k]
    strings = [str(integer) for integer in integers]
    a_string = "".join(strings)
    an_integer = int(a_string)
    for i in scores:
        if i > 0 and i >= an_integer:
            count += 1
    return count

print(nextRound(2,[1,1,1,1]))
```

here are the instructions for the question:

“If a contestant earns a score equal to or greater than the k-th place finisher, they will advance to the next round if their own score is greater than 0”. So write a function nextRound(k,scores) which will count how many contestants will progress to the next round.

Comment: I might not be following, but it looks like you are passing the argument to the method as integers, then changing them to strings afterwards. So far as I can tell those strings aren't used for anything. Is there more to the question?

Comment: the code gives me the answer i need. I just would like to know if there is a way of using a number from my list without my code being so convoluted. I slice the list to get my desired number using scores[k-1:k]. However, it returns my number in list form. Hence the 3 lines of code after that to convert it to an integer.  I need it as an integer so I can use it in my if statement. I just want to know if there is a better way than what I have done.

Comment: If the scores list has the player scores as a list of integers, and you need to access the k-th player score, why are you slicing the list at all and not just accessing that element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This accomplishes the same thing, I think you may be overthinking it by confusing a list of ints as also having the datatype list for its members:

```
def nextRound(k,scores):
    count = 0
    integer = scores[k]
    for i in scores:
        if i > 0 and i >= integer:
            count += 1
    return count

print(nextRound(2,[1,1,1,1]))
```

Running this gives the expected output of 4. This does assume that the scores are given presorted.